# 95% Confidence Interval for Proportions in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

How can I calculate a 95% interval to estimate the actual proportion of SUV's in the city in R? I would like to calculate the interval on this data:

```
vehicleType <- c("suv", "suv", "minivan", "car", "suv", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "car", "suv", "minivan", "car", "minivan", "suv", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "suv", "truck", "truck", "minivan", "suv", "car", "truck", "suv", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "suv", "suv", "minivan", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "suv", "car", "car", "suv", "minivan", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "minivan", "minivan", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "car", "minivan", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Besides speed, I'll bet that the non-coverage probability in at least one of the two tails is more accurate than the bootstrap.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, remember that an interval for a proportion is given by:

```
p_hat +/- z * sqrt(p_hat * (1-p_hat)/n)
```

With that being said, we can use R to solve the formula like so:

```
# Set CI alpha level (1-alpha/2)*100%
alpha = 0.05

# Load Data
vehicleType = c("suv", "suv", "minivan", "car", "suv", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "car", "suv", "minivan", "car", "minivan", "suv", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "suv", "truck", "truck", "minivan", "suv", "car", "truck", "suv", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "suv", "suv", "minivan", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "suv", "car", "car", "suv", "minivan", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "minivan", "minivan", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "car", "minivan", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car")

# Convert from string to factor
vehicleType = factor(vehicleType)

# Find the number of obs
n = length(vehicleType)

# Find number of obs per type
vtbreakdown = table(vehicleType)

# Get the proportion
p_hat = vtbreakdown['suv']/n

# Calculate the critical z-score
z = qnorm(1-alpha/2)

# Compute the CI
p_hat + c(-1,1)*z*sqrt(p_hat*(1-p_hat)/n)
```

So, we have:

```
0.1740293 0.3459707
```

For the `p_hat` of:

```
0.26
```

Comment: Should the "Compute the CI" code be `p_hat + c(-1.96,1.96)*sqrt(p_hat*(1-p_hat)/n)` for a 95% confidence interval (where `c(-1.96,1.96)` = -/+ the value of `z`)?

Comment: No need to do that @eipi10. Just forgot to include the `z`. @jason-todd note the correction needed.

Comment: Nice answer. It may be worth noting that the score interval tends to perform better in terms of coverage probabilities.

Comment: Will this formula work for small sample ?

Answer (score 21):

@Coatless's method will get the job done in most cases (including the OP's case). However, for completeness, I thought I'd add a couple of other options.

**Bootstrap Method**

The function below draws `n` resamples from the data vector. For each resample, it calculates the proportion of "successes" and then calculates the overall mean and 95% confidence interval

```
bp = function(x, lev, n = 1e3, alpha=0.05) {
  res = replicate(n, sum(sample(x, length(x), replace=TRUE) == lev)/length(x))
  return(list(mean=mean(res),
              `95% CI`=quantile(res, c(0.5*alpha,1-0.5*alpha))))
}

bp(vehicleType, "suv")

$mean
[1] 0.259628

$`95% CI`
  2.5% 97.5% 
  0.18  0.35
```

**`binom` Package**

The `binom` package will run the test in @Coatless's answer, which assumes the errors are normally distributed. This can result in incorrect values when the proportion of "successes" is near zero or one and/or if the sample is relatively small. `binom.confint` from the `binom` package has other options that avoid this pitfall.

In the output below, the `asymptotic` test is the same as the one coded by @Coatless. You can get the results for just one of the methods by using, for example, the `methods="exact"` argument. Also, `binom.test()` uses the exact (Pearson-Klopper) test by default.

```
library(binom)

binom.confint(sum(vehicleType=="suv"), length(vehicleType))

          method  x   n      mean     lower     upper
1  agresti-coull 26 100 0.2600000 0.1836007 0.3541561
2     asymptotic 26 100 0.2600000 0.1740293 0.3459707
3          bayes 26 100 0.2623762 0.1788095 0.3485750
4        cloglog 26 100 0.2600000 0.1787357 0.3485852
5          exact 26 100 0.2600000 0.1773944 0.3573121
6          logit 26 100 0.2600000 0.1835016 0.3545416
7         probit 26 100 0.2600000 0.1818365 0.3526030
8        profile 26 100 0.2600000 0.1808127 0.3513344
9            lrt 26 100 0.2600000 0.1808329 0.3513338
10     prop.test 26 100 0.2600000 0.1797427 0.3590222
11        wilson 26 100 0.2600000 0.1840470 0.3537099
```

Comment: I recommend Wilson's method which you can also get from the R `Hmisc` package `binconf` function.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, is there a reason to prefer Wilson's method over the bootstrap (or vice versa)? If the answer is too long for a comment, please feel free to link to something you or others have written about this.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are using a continuous normal distribution as an approximation of a discrete binomial distribution there should be a correction term added (0.5/N) to the above calculations:

[image]

[See here for more details](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/proportion_ci.html)